# Checking for absence of nulls and spaces in gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have developed a web application in ASP.NET C# which has a gridview. I am checking whether the value of a certain gridview column is null or a blank space. I have an if-else statement which depends on this column value. If the column in not a null or a blank space i'm entering the if part of the flow. Otherwise, I'm entering the else part of the flow.

```
       if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text))
        {
            Label1.Text = "[" + SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text + "]";

        }

        else
        {
            SqlUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@ForestgrpNew", null));
        }
```

In cases where the gridview column has a null value, the flow is expected to move to the else part. But the flow still passes on to the if part. Is there anything wrong with (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text)) in checking whether the cell is neither a null nor a space?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` should work like you expect. Have you gone through step by step with the debugger and checked the actual value of  `SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text`?

Answer (score 0):

Debug the code.  In one of my cases, the GridView was inserting `&nbsp;`, probably to play nice with IE tablecell issues.

Change your if statement to something like below to remove any non-breaking space characters:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text.replace("&nbsp;", "") ) )
```